# Avoid referencing parent scope in angularjs directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am writing a directive to display data from server in an HTML table called `djlist`

```
directive('djlist', function(urls) {
    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        templateUrl: urls.list_objs_template,
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', '$resource', 
            function($scope, $resource) {
                $scope.objs = $resource(urls.list_objs);
                $scope.objs_api = $resource(urls.list_objs_api);
                $scope.data = $scope.objs.get();
            }
        ]
    };
})
```

The data from server are displayed with `ng-repeat`. Each object in the data array has a delete button attached to it, which is another directive called `djdel`

```
<div class="row panel panel-primary">
    <h3 class="panel-heading">Data from REST</h3>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Content</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="d in data.objects">
                <td>{{ d.content }}</td>
                <td>{{ d.date }}</td>
                <td>
                    <djdel ng-click="del($index)" model-pk="d.id"></djdel>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is how I define `djdel`

```
directive('djdel', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'ACE',
        template: '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-small">Delete</button>',
        scope: {
            modelPk: '='
        }, controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 
            function($scope, $http, $resource) {
                $scope.del = function(index) {
                    var $parent = $scope.$parent.$parent;
                    $parent.objs_api.
                    remove({id: $scope.modelPk}, function() {
                        $parent.data.objects.splice(index, 1);
                    });
                };
            }
        ]
    };
}).
```

This works. However, after my object is successfully deleted from the server, which is initiated in the `djdel scope`, I need a way to refresh the data collection, which is in the `djlist scope`. The scope hierarchy is `djlist > ng-repeat > djdel`, hence `$scope.$parent.$parent` when referencing data collection.

Is there any way to avoid referencing so many levels up the scope chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can `require` the parent controller: In `djdel`:

```
directive('djdel', function() {
    return {
        ...
        require: "^djlist",
        ...
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, djlistController) {
            // the controller function does not have access to the required
            // controllers, so we just inject htem in the scope
            scope.djlistController = djlistController;
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', '$resource', 
            function($scope, $http, $resource) {
                // you can access members of the djlistController as
                $scope.djlistController.XXX();
                ...
            }]
    };
});
```

In `djlist` add the required functions to `this` (NOT TO THE `$scope`):

```
directive('djlist', function(urls) {
    ...
    controller: ['$scope', '$resource',
        function($scope, $resource) {
            this.XXX = function() {
                // you can also add variables here
            };
            ...
        }]
    ...
});
```

Comment: Very clean. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try emitting events in the `$rootScope` of your application.

```
$rootScope.$broadcast("nameOfTheEvent", paramsToSend);
```

Right after you erase something from the server and

```
$rootScope.$on("nameOftheEvent", function(paramsToRecieve) { refreshList();});
```

Of course, paramsToRecieve is paramsToSend and can be any object.

Comment: The method called on $rootScope should be $broadcast not emit. Emit goes up, broadcast goes down. $rootScope is top scope so broadcast is needed.